# epoll_ctl() failed: No such file or directory [errno = 2]

Tags: linux, redhat, epoll

Recently updated the Linux kernel from 2.6.18 to 2.6.32, and an existing application starts error out with following error message:

epoll_ctl() failed: No such file or directory [errno = 2].

I did read through the linux man page on epoll_ctl but couldn't make much sense of it. I am trying to understand what the possible cause of such?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give us the code calling `epoll_ctl`, but likely the socket behind the file descriptor you are trying to modify has been closed somewhere else. See also [Epoll: does it silently remove fds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987302/epoll-does-it-silently-remove-fds)

Comment: Thanks, Bacon. Just noticed your response. The issue has been resolved and thanks for your reply. You are correct - the descriptor was indeed closed unexpectedly.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it matched the problem :)