# Epoll: does it silently remove fds?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, epoll, libev

I've been reading through [libev's source code](https://github.com/enki/libev/blob/master/ev_epoll.c) and stumbled upon this comment:

> a) epoll silently removes fds from the fd set. as nothing tells us that an fd has been removed otherwise, we have to continually "rearm" fds that we suspect *might* have changed (same problem with kqueue, but much less costly there).

I've been doing some tests with epoll (directly using syscalls) on some modern linux kernel and I couldn't reproduce it. I didn't see any problem with "silently disappearing fds". Could someone elaborate on this and tell me if it's still an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather vague text there, but I guess it is just that if the descriptor is `close`d elsewhere, it is silently removed from the set. From Linux manpages, [epoll(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html):

> **Q6**  Will closing a file descriptor  cause  it  to  be
>              removed from all epoll sets automatically?
>
> **A6**  Yes, but be aware of the following point.  A file
>              descriptor  is  a  reference  to  an  open   file
>              description (see `open(2)`).  Whenever a descriptor
>              is  duplicated  via  `dup(2)`,  `dup2(2)`,   `fcntl(2)`
>              `F_DUPFD`, or `fork(2)`, a new file descriptor refer‐
>              ring to the same open file  description  is  cre‐
>              ated.   An  open  file  description  continues to
>              exist until all file descriptors referring to  it
>              have  been  closed.  A file descriptor is removed
>              from  an  epoll  set  only  after  all  the  file
>              descriptors referring to the underlying open file
>              description have been closed (or  before  if  the
>              descriptor    is    explicitly    removed   using
>              `epoll_ctl(2)`  `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`).   This  means  that
>              even  after  a file descriptor that is part of an
>              epoll set has been closed, events may be reported
>              for  that  file descriptor if other file descrip‐
>              tors  referring  to  the  same  underlying   file
>              description remain open.

So you have a socket with fd 42. It gets `close`d, and subsequently removed from the `epoll` object. But the kernel doesn't notify the `libev` about this *through* `epoll_wait`. Now the `epoll_modify` is called again with fd = `42`. `epoll_modify` doesn't know whether this file descriptor 42 the same that already was in the `epoll` object or some other file description with the file descriptor number 42 reused.

One could also argue that the comments are just ranting and the design of the `libev` API is at fault here.

Comment: Definitely ranting. External `close` shouldn't *ever* be used regardless of reactor. There should just be `detach` and `remove_and_close` methods *on* the reactor.