# Do I need to manually EPOLL_CTL_DEL the event after only a EPOLLONESHOT event has been triggered when closing the socket?

Tags: c, epoll

```
struct epoll_event ev, events[20];
ev.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLONESHOT;
ev.data.sock = some_socket;
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, some_socket, &ev);
// then the EPOLLOUT event has triggered by epoll_wait
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, some_socket, NULL); // should it be called? will it cause error?
```

after the EPOLLOUT event has been triggered, the MAN page said the event has now been disabled and will not triggered. I don't know if it's completely same as EPOLL_CTL_DEL.
Do I need to manually call EPOLL_CTL_DEL when closing the socket if EPOLLOUT | EPOLLONESHOT is the only event that has been triggered?

Answer (score 0):

"When closing the socket" implies you do not need `epoll_ctl` with `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` unless there other fine moments. Did you duplicate the fd? No? Then you don't need to. Yes? May depend on the program logic: whether or not you need that socket to close now or it is still monitored. For details please read here:
[Epoll: does it silently remove fds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987302/epoll-does-it-silently-remove-fds)